# I got a error when i'm trying to run my script. Coogle Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I got a script but it dosn't work:

```
    function onOpen(e){
  var sheet = Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Load all the URLs
  var urls = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  //Initialize array for content
  var text = [];

  //Loop through URLs
  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i += 1){
    //Fetch the webpage, push the content to the array (inside an array since it needs to be 2d)
    text.push(
      [UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i][0]).getContentText()]
    );
  }
  //Store text in spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange("B:B").setValues(text);
}
```

it goes forward, but stuck in string 13: Attribute is specified with no value: url (string · 13). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the second line. It should read:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: Thank you, it goes forward, but stuck in string 13: Attribute is specified with no value: url (string · 13). Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know enough to help with that - other than suggesting you use the debugger to step through the for loop and see if that gives you any clues but you're probably doing that already.

Comment: are url[i][0] valid urls ?

Comment: Yes, valid. Debug shows me that data of web page was taken. But the program can not display them in column B.

Comment: maybe you could try `sheet.getRange(1,1,text.length,text[0].length).setValues(text);`